# Python - Json write, Doesn't want to print out as I wish

Tags: python, json

Im trying to do a write from my script to make it a Json file.

However when I write out with my script it gives me a output of

```
{
    "profile_1": {
        "email": "HelloWorld",
        "pswrd": "WorldHello123"
    }
} {
    "profile_2": {
        "email": "HelloWorld",
        "pswrd": "WorldHello123"
    }
} {
    "profile_3": {
        "email": "HelloWorld",
        "pswrd": "WorldHello123"
    }
}
```

Which I really wished for is:

```
"profile_0": {
            "email": "HelloWorld",
            "pswrd": "WorldHello123"

        },
        "profile_1": {
            "email": "HelloWorld",
            "pswrd": "WorldHello123""
        },
        "profile_2": {
            "email": "HelloWorld",
            "pswrd": "WorldHello123"
        },
        "profile_3": {
            "email": "HelloWorld",
            "pswrd": "WorldHello123"
        },
```

and as we compare there is { } too many and also , missing which I can't quite understand why it wouldnt work. This is how my script works:

```
import json

    with open("test.txt") as accounts:
        for splitlines in accounts:
            temp = accounts.read().splitlines()
            username, password = zip(*(s.split(":") for s in temp))
            linelength = len(username)

            with open("profiles.json", "a") as profile:
                lineInt = 0
                while (lineInt < linelength):
                    lineInt += 1
                    jsonData = {
                            "profile_" + str(lineInt): {
                            "email": username[lineInt],
                            "pswrd": password[lineInt]
                            }
                    }
                    json.dump(jsonData, profile)
```

I have been sitting too long to not see the problem :'(

Comment: You should only have **one** `json.dump`; build a list of dictionaries, then write *that* to the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outputting *JSON objects* one by one.
If you want to output a *JSON array*,
you should put the objects in a list, and print that, for example:

```
lineInt = 0
items = []
while (lineInt < linelength):
    jsonData = {
        "profile_" + str(lineInt): {
            "email": username[lineInt],
            "pswrd": password[lineInt]
        }
    }
    lineInt += 1
    items.append(jsonData)
json.dump(items, profile)
```

Comment: Oh yes, I can now see the issue. But I dont see why your exempel wouldn't work because it looks good for me atleast? It does say my email is "tuple index out of range"

Comment: @Andres123 that was because of another bug in your code, incrementing `lineInt` too early. I fixed it now, see the updated answer

Comment: Yes exactly! Just found it out aswell! There we go!